# Strange file with impossible name in my home directory

Tags: filesystems

I have a strange file that appeared in my home directory a couple of days ago:

[image]

`ls` in bash gives me the following output:

```
Âõ(\'e@\Âõ(\7@\Âõ(,e@ëQ¸8@jon.xojcA
```

In `fish`, `ls` quotes the names shell-safe by default and gives me this:

```
''$'\217\302\365''(\'\''e@\'$'\217\302\365''(\7@\'$'\217\302\365''(,e@'$'\037\205\353''Q'$'\270\036''8@jon.xojcA'
```

I cannot delete that file in Dolphin because it does not seem to exist. I guess there is a bug in Dolphin that it cannot work with such a pathologic filename. I managed to delete it with `rm` on the command line and tab-completion.

Where could this file have come from? I use the EXT4 filesystem with LUKS encryption on Fedora 25. The partition is a bit older, I created that 2015-Oct-20 (around that month). Is this something I should worry about?

Comment: You should be able to delete it with `rm *8@jon.xojcA` unless other files have names that matches that pattern.

Comment: To answer your last question, I don't worry too much about something like this the _first_ time it happens if nothing seems to be lost or damaged.  I've seen what you described, the out-of-nowhere screwy file name, a couple times in a lot of years.  I've written it off as "corruption of unknown source" ;)  I would love if someone had a real answer though.

Comment: I've had this happen when accidentally using `cat` on a binary file, straight out onto the console.

Comment: This is a bit old, but I've had this happen several times over the last year or so, and I notice we're both using `fish`... which made me think a bit, my starting to use `fish` very roughly correlates with the first occurrence of this weird issue. Probably a coincidence, right? Anyway, do you still use `fish`, and have you found more weird files growing in your home directory since you posted this?

Comment: @trentcl: I could not recall any more of these events.

Comment: Hmm. I'll keep looking. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where could this file have come from?

You're asking for pure speculation here, but just one possible path is filesystem or terminal data stream corruption.

An example of filesystem corruption is that the disk block where the file's name is stored is somehow corrupt, yet in such a way that all of its checksums match. (Without that last provision, the filesystem would simply refuse to retrieve that corrupted data.) This could happen due to bad RAM, a failing hard drive, dodgy cabling, cosmic rays...

An example of terminal data stream corruption is when using an RS-232 serial line (or something that emulates it) or one of the relatively tolerant protocols contemporaneous with the reign of RS-232, such as [Zmodem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM).

Zmodem is still convenient in the days of SSH and `scp` because it sneaks the file data through the connection you already have; you don't have to somehow switch the SSH connection into SCP mode or establish a separate SCP connection. The [`lrzsz` package](https://ohse.de/uwe/software/lrzsz.html) works naturally with SSH and Unix command lines.

Zmodem-over-SSH is especially convenient when SSH'd in through a chain of two or more hosts, but there's a trap. If you use the default `rz` options to try and Zmodem a binary file through the link, it is likely that some byte sequence in the file will be seen as an [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) or [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) by the intermediary SSH host which doesn't realize it is relaying a Zmodem transfer, causing it to misinterpret the data stream, corrupting the Zmodem transfer. (The fix, incidentally, is to use `rz -e` to force escaping of control characters.)

When something like this happens, the ongoing data stream is being misinterpreted, so that suddenly a data transfer can turn into commands to the shell, and if something in that command stream happens to match a real command (e.g. `cat > h34ijth34u8934`) the shell creates a file with a garbage name. As far as the shell is concerned, you asked it to do that. The shell doesn't know that the source of the "typed" file name is a remote `sz` program spewing file data at it after the local `rz` program it was talking to died.

(Yes, this has actually happened to me, multiple times.)

> Is this something I should worry about?

It depends on how it happened, which again calls for speculation.

Comment: I remember using `cat` (or `less`) on some binary file and had the screen filled with garbage. Or I had accidentally copied some junk into some shell where it got interpreted this way. --- Yes, it is hard to reconstruct that, I see. I'll just ignore it, then.

Answer (score 4):

This will show you inode of the file:

```
ls -lai
```

Than you can delete it:

```
find . -type f -inum (inode)
```

... but I would advice to check what is in the file first. Try to execute `file` on it:

`find . type f -inum (inode) -exec file {} \;`

Than you can open it with `vim` same way.

Comment: I was able to delete my strange file by changing `-exec file {} \;` with `-exec rm {} \;`. Thanks! I suspect mine is due to SD card corruption on my Raspberry Pi, something I've encountered before.